# Plotting a cylinder using ListPlot3d

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics, graphics3d, image3d

I have a table of dimensions {$\theta$,$z$}= {20,200} that I want to plot as a cylinder instead of a plane.

The code I have is:

```
thetaPts = 20;
thetaVals = Table[2 Pi  i/thetanPts, {i, 0, thetaPts - 1}];
zPts = 200;
zVals = Table[z, {z, 0, zPts - 1}];
cylinderVals = Table[1, {theta, thetaVals}, {z, zVals}];
ListPlot3D[cylinderVals, AxesLabel -> {"z", "\[Theta]"}]
```

Which gives this 3D plot:

[image: Plane that I want to be wrapped around a cylinder]

Is there any way to plot the output from `ListPlot3D` as a 3d cylinder (with $\theta$ being the azimuthal direction and $z$ being the axial direction) instead of a plane?

I have other surfaces I want to wrap around cylinders so I want to find out how to do this with `ListPlot3D`.

Answer (score 2):

A cylinder with a height of e.g. 10 :

```
d = Flatten[
   Table[{Cos[p], Sin[p], z}, {p, 0, 2 Pi, Pi/10}, {z, 0, 10}], 1];
ListSurfacePlot3D[d]
```

[image]